BeanCreationException, How to troubleshoot?
Hello StackOverflow community,
I'm encountering an issue with a NullPointerException occurring within the ShopPromotionScheduler class in my Spring Boot application.
I'm relatively new to implementing schedulers in my code, and I'm encountering an issue that I'm having trouble diagnosing. Specifically, I'm getting a NullPointerException, but I'm uncertain about its source.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
@Component
public class ShopPromotionScheduler {

    @Resource
    private IShopPromotionService shopPromotionService;

    @Resource
    private IShopItemBossBusinessService shopItemBossBusinessService;

    @Resource
    private IShopAutoSaleBossBusinessService shopAutoSaleBossBusinessService;

    private Logger bizLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Constants.BIZ_LOGGER);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        startScheduler();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void checkAndUpdateShopPromo() {
        ShopPromotionQuery param = new ShopPromotionQuery();
        param.setStatus(1);
        List<ShopPromotionVo> shopPromotionList = shopPromotionService.getShopPromotionList(param).getModel();

        bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromotionList:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromotionList));
        shopPromotionList.forEach(shopPromo -> {
            bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromo:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromo));
            if (checkPastTime(shopPromo.getEndTime())){
                shopPromo.getShopPromotionItemVoList().forEach(itemPromo -> {
                    bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler itemPromo:{}", JSON.toJSONString(itemPromo));
                    ShopItemQuery shopItemQuery = new ShopItemQuery();
                    shopItemQuery.setEntityId(itemPromo.getEntityId());
                    shopItemQuery.setId(itemPromo.getItemId());
                    ShopItemDetailsVo shopItemDetailsVo = new ShopItemDetailsVo();
                    try {
                        shopItemDetailsVo = shopItemBossBusinessService.getShopItemDetails(shopItemQuery).getModel();
                        bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopItemDetailsVo:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopItemDetailsVo));
                        if (shopItemDetailsVo == null)
                            throw new RuntimeException();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    ShopItemSetParam shopItemSetParam = itemSetParam(shopItemDetailsVo);
                    shopItemSetParam.setIsPromo(0);
                    ShopPromotionQuery shopPromotionParam = new ShopPromotionQuery();
                    shopPromotionParam.setId(itemPromo.getShopPromotionId());
                    bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromotionParam:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromotionParam));
                    List<ShopPromotionVo> shopPromotion = shopPromotionService.getShopPromotionList(shopPromotionParam).getModel();
                    bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromotion:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromotion));
                    boolean isUpdate = true;
                    for (ShopPromotionVo shopPromotionVo : shopPromotion) {
                        bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromotionVo:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromotionVo));
                        if (!(Objects.equals(shopPromotionVo.getId(), itemPromo.getShopPromotionId()))) {
                            if (shopPromotionVo.getStatus() == 1){
                                isUpdate = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (isUpdate) {
                        bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler isUpdate:{}", JSON.toJSONString(isUpdate));
                        Result<String> updateResult = shopItemBossBusinessService.updateShopItem(shopItemSetParam);
                        bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler updateResult:{}", JSON.toJSONString(updateResult));
                    }

                });
                ShopPromotionParam shopPromotionParam = new ShopPromotionParam();
                shopPromotionParam.setEntityId(shopPromotionParam.getEntityId());
                shopPromotionParam.setId(shopPromotionParam.getId());
                shopPromotionParam.setStatus(2);
                bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler shopPromotionParam:{}", JSON.toJSONString(shopPromotionParam));
                Result<Integer> result = shopPromotionService.updateShopPromotion(shopPromotionParam);
                bizLogger.info("checkAndUpdateShopPromo shopPromoScheduler result:{}", JSON.toJSONString(result));
            };
        });
    }

    private void startScheduler(){
        checkAndUpdateShopPromo();
    }

    private boolean checkPastTime(Long timestamp){
        Duration duration = Duration.between(Instant.now(), Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp));
        return duration.isNegative() || duration.isZero();
    }

    private ShopItemSetParam itemSetParam(ShopItemDetailsVo shopItemDetailsVo) throws Exception {
        ShopAutoOnOffSaleQuery shopAutoOnOffSaleQuery = new ShopAutoOnOffSaleQuery();
        shopAutoOnOffSaleQuery.setEntityId(shopItemDetailsVo.getEntityId());
        shopAutoOnOffSaleQuery.setItemId(shopItemDetailsVo.getId());
        ShopItemSetParam shopItemSetParam = new ShopItemSetParam();
        ShopAutoOnOffSaleVo shopAutoOnOffSaleVo = new ShopAutoOnOffSaleVo();
        try {
            shopAutoSaleBossBusinessService.getShopAutoOnOffSale(shopAutoOnOffSaleQuery).getModel();
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        ShopAutoOnOffSaleParam shopAutoOnOffSaleParam = new ShopAutoOnOffSaleParam();
        shopAutoOnOffSaleParam.setId(shopAutoOnOffSaleVo.getId());
        shopAutoOnOffSaleParam.setEntityId(shopAutoOnOffSaleVo.getEntityId());
        shopAutoOnOffSaleParam.setIsAutoSale(shopAutoOnOffSaleVo.getIsAutoSale());
        shopAutoOnOffSaleParam.setIsWeekday(shopAutoOnOffSaleVo.getIsWeekday());
        shopAutoOnOffSaleParam.setItemId(shopAutoOnOffSaleVo.getItemId());

        shopItemSetParam.setId(shopItemDetailsVo.getId());
        shopItemSetParam.setOpUserId(shopItemDetailsVo.getOpUserId());
        shopItemSetParam.setEntityId(shopItemDetailsVo.getEntityId());
        shopItemSetParam.setShopAutoOnOffSaleParamList(shopAutoOnOffSaleParam);
        shopItemSetParam.setItemType(shopItemDetailsVo.getItemType());
        shopItemSetParam.setSubType(shopItemDetailsVo.getSubType());
        shopItemSetParam.setCategoryId(shopItemDetailsVo.getCategoryId());
        shopItemSetParam.setItemName(shopItemDetailsVo.getItemName());
        shopItemSetParam.setItemSubName(shopItemDetailsVo.getItemSubName());
        shopItemSetParam.setItemCode(shopItemDetailsVo.getItemCode());
        shopItemSetParam.setStartNum(shopItemDetailsVo.getStartNum());
        shopItemSetParam.setIsShelves(shopItemDetailsVo.getIsShelves());
        shopItemSetParam.setIsTakeout(shopItemDetailsVo.getIsTakeout());
        shopItemSetParam.setIsDiscount(shopItemDetailsVo.getIsDiscount());
        shopItemSetParam.setIsRecommend(shopItemDetailsVo.getIsRecommend());
        shopItemSetParam.setIsSku(shopItemDetailsVo.getIsSku());
        shopItemSetParam.setDetails(shopItemDetailsVo.getDetails());
        shopItemSetParam.setDualUnit(shopItemDetailsVo.getDualUnit());
        shopItemSetParam.setBarCode(shopItemDetailsVo.getBarCode());
        shopItemSetParam.setSortCode(shopItemDetailsVo.getSortCode());
        shopItemSetParam.setMemo(shopItemDetailsVo.getMemo());

        return shopItemSetParam;
    }
}

this is the log error;
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-01 17:47:50.361 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure:771 Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shopPromotionScheduler': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1623)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.platform.merchant.StartSpringBootApplication.main(StartSpringBootApplication.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.itemSetParam(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:122)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.lambda$null$0(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:72)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.lambda$checkAndUpdateShopPromo$1(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:58)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.checkAndUpdateShopPromo(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:55)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.startScheduler(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:107)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.init(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)

I am trying to implement a way to create a code with a scheduler. However, when I have implemented it, there is an error like that. I'm not too sure where I went wrong because I have tried several different scheduler methods and none of them have worked
PS: its already solved, forget to put @EnableScheduling lol

Please check which line is 122 of the file?
You can see the error at: com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.itemSetParam(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:122)

I don't think your problem is related to the Spring scheduler. The stack trace indicates a problem accessing an ArrayList element.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.itemSetParam(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:122)
        at com.platform.merchant.component.ShopPromotionScheduler.lambda$null$0(ShopPromotionScheduler.java:72)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259) 

It may caused by accessing an empty object within the forEach loop in the checkAndUpdateShopPromo method in the ShopPromotionScheduler class. You may check that the shopPromotionService   returns an initialized object.
List<ShopPromotionVo> shopPromotionList = shopPromotionService.getShopPromotionList(param).getModel();

